# How to override block .php file?

Tags: magento2, blocks, overrides

I got this file:

> module-sales/Block/Adminhtml/Order/Create/Shipping/Method/Form.php

I want to override this in a custom module.

How can I do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Block use the below code in your module's di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Shipping\Method\Form" type="[VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Shipping\Method\Form"/>
</config>
```

For phtml override create a xml file with name sales_order_create_load_block_shipping_method.xml on your module's layout folder and set template for this "order.create.shipping.method.form" and use your template file location as per the requirement.

Comment: Thanks! Where should I put the di.xml?

Comment: yes, added etc/di.xml

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

> app/code/Namespace/ModuleName/etc/

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <module name="Magenticians_Modulecontact" setup_version="1.0.1">
  </module>
</config>
```

> app/code/Namespace/ModuleName/registration.php

```
<?php
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Magenticians_Modulecontact',
    __DIR__
);
```

> app/code/Namespace/ModuleName/etc/di.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Shipping\Method\Form" type="[Namespace]\[ModuleName]\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Shipping\Method\Form" />
</config>
```

> Run : php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> Run : php bin/magento c:c